# Tmux blocks keybinding like Ctrl-Enter from nvim

Tags: tmux, neovim

I use Neovim and rely on the keybinding "ctrl + enter" for doing a specific action. When I'm in Tmux, this keybinding does not work. I have not made any changes to the Tmux defaults.

Is there a way to make my keybinding work inside of Tmux?